# Ubuntu VPS not running cronjob

Tags: ubuntu, vps, cron

I used `sudo crontab -e` to add the following cronjob 
`0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/path/to/artisan elite:reset-user-likes`

The command works correctly if a type it myself on the terminal.

I also tried setting the cronjob to run every minute to see if it works but it didn't.

How can I check what's wrong with the cronjob ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would check syslog & have a look what kind of error message the crond is producing. If you are not getting any output, try adding the -e php option. Secondly, try using quotes ("cmd") around the command. There may be a problem interpreting the command options.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: In the syslog a get the following message "Authentication token is no longer valid; new one required"

Comment: That problem (expired password for root) is covered in one of the answers to the question pointed at in Deer Hunter's comment.